# How to convert a .urdf file to .sdf 1.4 format

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

gzsdf print pr2.urdf > pr2.sdf gives errors in gazebo 1.7.1

Error [parser.cc:719] XML Element[turnGravityOff], child of element[link] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[link]
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element `<link>`
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element `<model>`
Error [parser.cc:369] Unable to read element `<sdf>`
Error [parser.cc:291] parse as old deprecated model file failed.

why does gzsdf fail?

Thank you
Peshala

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2569/how-to-convert-a-.urdf-file-to-.sdf-1.4-format/) by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 197 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2013-04-26**:
why does Gazebo still requires ros-fuerte-urdfdom by the way? (I am using Groovy)

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-04-26**:
Ubuntu Precise builds of Gazebo require `ros-fuerte-urdfdom` because we wanted to limit the number of ubuntu/ros/gazebo builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Tags like `<turnGravityOff>` no longer exists in new sdf format and in fact being replaced by `<gravity>` and so on. By manually changing these tags accordingly I could convert the urdf to sdf.

---

Originally posted by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) with karma: 197 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0